# Mocking Stream or Reader in Java Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, java-io

I have following two services to generate a CSV file from a given file. And trying to test each services. However could not fig out how to mock Stream/Reader.

```
@Servce
public class MyService {
  public void process() {
    List<String> fileNames =  someService.collectFileNames();
    fileNames.forEach(currFile -> {
      try {
        FileInputStream currFileStream = new FileInputStream(currFile);
        InputStreamReader currFileStreamReader = new InoutStreamReader(currFileStream, UTF_8);
        Reader currFileReader = new BufferedReader(currFileStreamReader);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { ... }
    }
   }
 }

 @Service
 public class MyFileProcessor {
   public void createCVSFile(Reader fileReader) {
     CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, ...);
     ...
   }
 }
```

I am getting `FileNotFoundExcpetion` when mocking stream and even passing `any()` on mock function.

Any suggestion?

Comment: There is never any reason to mock a reader.  Just create a `StringReader` or some other different `Reader` implementation.

Comment: You'll need to refactor your code to be more testable, so that you can mock the creation of the `Stream`.

Comment: And you say that you are having a problem "when mocking stream" but you don't show the code that's doing the mocking.